# Dynamically add Layout after some layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example

```
<LinearLayout>

   <TextView />
   <ImageView />

   <Button />
   <RelativeLayout />
   <ImageView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now how to add dynamicly Layout after Button?

If i get first (root) Layout and i `addView()` adds in the end.

Comment: Whereever you want to add any views dynamically just put a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout at that place and add the dynamically created views to that layout. In you example Relativelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty `LinearLayout` where you want your views placed dynamically, and add the views to that layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `RelativeLayout` as parent layout.

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout>

   <TextView />
   <ImageView />

   <Button />
   <RelativeLayout />
   <ImageView/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.existing_layout);

newView.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes but if it's RelativeLayout then i need to tell RelativeLayout bellow button, and then my 'wanted' Layout below button.

Comment: Check [this](http://www.androidpit.com/forum/588008/add-view-programmatically-to-relativelayout-android) post. That explains very well. @user1730007

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent on the click event of your button , in order to navigate between the different layouts

```
Intent i= new Intent((your class).this,(layout class that you want).class);
start Activity(i);
```